# Need help clearing compiler errors from simple jQuery function

Tags: jquery, variables, compiler-errors

In my jQuery file I have the following script:

```
function incDistInput(){

$(".incInputBtn").on("click", function() {

    var $button = $(this),
        oldValue = $button.siblings("input").val(),
        quantity = oldValue.split(' miles');

    if ($button.hasClass('plusBtn')) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(quantity[0]) + 1;
    } else {

    if (quantity[0] > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(quantity[0]) - 1;
        } else {
        newVal = 0;
        }
    }

    $button.siblings("input").val(newVal + ' miles');

});

}
```

This function is giving the following errors at compile time:

```
var newVal = parseFloat(quantity[0]) - 1;
'newVal' is defined but never used. — column 17
'newVal' is already defined. — column 24

newVal = 0;
'newVal' used out of scope. — column 13

$button.siblings("input").val(newVal + ' miles');
'newVal' used out of scope. — column 39
```

How can I rearrange or otherwise define these variables to clear out the errors without changing the function’s output?

Comment: Try defining newVal before the if conditions. Just put `var newVal = 0;` anywhere before the first condition;

Comment: I tried this as you can see below, but it gives a different error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialize the `newVal` outside your `if` statement, so it could be recognized..

```
var $button = $(this),
    oldValue = $button.siblings("input").val(),
    quantity = oldValue.split(' miles')
    var newVal = 0;

if ($button.hasClass('plusBtn')) {
    newVal = parseFloat(quantity[0]) + 1;
} else {

if (quantity[0] > 0) {
    newVal = parseFloat(quantity[0]) - 1;
    } else {
    newVal = 0;
    }
}

$button.siblings("input").val(newVal + ' miles');
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gives a new error `var newVal = parseFloat(quantity[0]) + 1; 'newVal' is already defined. — column 24`

Comment: Well of course, you are trying to define it again. You should define with `var newVal` at the top, and then just use it with `newVal = parseFloat...`